# changing my div with this Ques in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to change the first question in the code to be the same as the first question in the array all questions

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first questionair page</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <div id= question>
<ul class="question-list">
```

here is the question i want to change

```
  <LH id=que>gfh</LH>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice1" data-price="100" value="product1" checked="checked">
    <label for="choice1"><span>question 1</span></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice2" data-price="110" value="choice2"><label for="choice2"><span>question 2 [+ 10 $]</span></label>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice3" data-price="110" value="product3"><label for="product3"><span>question 3 [+ 10 $]</span></label>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="jqtest" value="next"  onclick= nextQuestion_onclick>
</div>
</form>
```

now the javascript i want the question who is the prime minister of the uk in the question

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var allQuestions = [{question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], correctAnswer:0}];
```

here i tried to connect the question:(

```
$(document).ready(function(){
allQuestions[0].question= $('#que');

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: could you please create a fiddle of your code so that i can help you.

Comment: To select an element by ID in jQ, you can do $('#que'). Without the hashtag, it thinks you are looking by tag name.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yz90a367/1/

Comment: sorry was in a rush still doesnt work check out the new js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this function:

```
$('#que').text(allQuestions[0].question)
```

Instead of

```
allQuestions[0].question= $('#que').text()
```

Working JSFiddle:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/yz90a367/2/)